# How to catch the exception address in Application_error (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

If I have a page on my ASP.NET MVC site called

http://www.example.com/document/first

but someone tries to access

```
http://www.example.com/documents/first
http://www.example.com/first
```

The page will error and application_error will fire because it can't find a controller for documents.  How do I get the error address in Application_error.  I don't seem to get the whole raw url i.e. /documents/first

Before there's the suggestion of adding a route or a URL Rewrite, I don't want to do that because there can be tens of different possible error addresses.

I just want to know the web address of the missing page in the application_error.

After the application-error function has been called, it goes to the error page that I've set up in the web.config and that gets the URL and processes it accordingly but I want to do the processing in the global.asax so there's no redirecting involved.

Comment: Read [ask]. If you can't verify the answers immediately, don't ask a question until you can.

Comment: Ok, that question solved it, didn't find it earlier, looking for catch answer instead of throw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one :
get exception in Application_Error method in Global.asax

```
 protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
             var url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.OriginalString;
 }
}
```

Comment: why downvoted? person should mention the reason if they do so.

Comment: @Liam He wants to know the wrong url that was tried. That's what is answered.

Comment: No, you show how to get the last exception. Parsing the exception message is not the way to get the requested URL.

Comment: @CodeCaster ok, I changed the answer now